# Index out of range in C#

Tags: c#, exception, range

I tried to debug this code, but I cannt how to fix it.
If I use this code, my WF run:

```
try 
{                       

    rtxttdwhat.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    lbtdtime1.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() +
            ":" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

the other, it's show INDEX OUT OF RANGE:

```
int a, b;
a = 1;
b = a+1;
try 
{
    if (int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value.ToString()) == int.Parse(lbhour.Text) &&             
        int.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value.ToString()) == int.Parse(lbmin.Text))
    {
        a = a + 1;
        b = a + 1;
    }
    rtxttdwhat.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[8].Value.ToString();
    lbtdtime1.Text = dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + 
            ":" + dataGridView1.Rows[a].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: are you sure Rows[a] is not going out of bound i,.e you may have only 5 rows but a has current value 6 so your a[6] is actually not valid then. Please verify that first

Comment: what are you extacly doing with var b.. I do not see you are using anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what are you doing, especially with `b`? But you could try this:

```
int RowCount = dataGridView1.Rows.Count;
if(a <= RowCount)
{
     //Youre Code
}
else
{
    //Out of Range
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi This link may be useful for you
[IndexOutOfRangeException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.indexoutofrangeexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Modify your code and Check for Rows and Cells Counts first before accessing them.